# From Internship to Probationary. Is this normal?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, management, career-development, internship

I've been an intern at a company where they gave me a task for Web Development. From time to time I've learned so much. After my 6 months of Internship the CEO and my supervisor decided to absorb me but I have to take 6 months of training again as a probationary. Out of my thirst for more experience and learning I've agreed with it.

On my 6 months term, Two of the regular employees we're terminated due to their "low performance". I've heard gossips from my coworkers that they were terminated also because of me.

Nearly Ending my 6 months term as a probationary,
I've been assigned as a Team lead to some of my coworkers("Regular Employees"). also I've been handled so many numerous task simultaneously. Like I have to do my everyday job while leading my members, Training OJT's, Answering questions from my coworkers, Doing Both Front End Web and Back End Web, Not to mention Graphics Designs jobs while numerously testing it and sometimes even including one of the job of my supervisor. It was very stressful for me as a probationary employee to go through such a multi tasking environment.

What are the best way to avoid such treatment on incoming interns or fresh graduates?

Comment: How exactly does the gossip mean that they were terminated because of you? To your question: Set up an internal guideline on how to treat and teach interns and fresh graduates or generally everybody new joining the company. If it is there, ask to review it based on current experiences (not only of yourself but also others).

Comment: FWIW this isn't just limited to intern-permanent.  I finished out the day reading the new version of my employer's policy manual; they'll do one for any internal promotion.

Answer (score 2):

It is very common for an intern that's converted to a permanent employee be given a probationary period.  In all honesty you're a new hire, just the same as if someone was hired off of the street for the same position.

Gossip means nothing, they weren't fired because of you, they were fired because they weren't doing their job up to expectations.  Maybe the fact that you can do the job better than them contributed to the decision, but it was ultimately made because of their performance.

The probationary period exists so both you and the employer can decide if the job is a good fit.  Obviously you will have different expectations and different tasks as a permanent employee as compared to being an intern, so it's fair for them to evaluate you in the new position.

Comment: "In all honesty you're a new hire, just the same as if someone was hired off of the street for the same position." That makes no sense. How is an intern transitioning into an employee just the same as someone hired off the street?

Comment: Because you are being hired for a different position than the one you're currently working in.  You have knowledge of the company's products so that can give you an advantage over other candidates.  

As I said though, what is expected of you is different as a permanent employee than when you were an intern.  The probationary period is there to see how you do in a different position.  

Now this isn't standard but it is the company's policy and you agreed to it by accepting the position.

Comment: As a non programming example when I got promoted to a management position I was on a probationary period. It just means that if you don't fulfill expectations for your new position you can be demoted/fired. It's wicked common across multiple industries.